# App not creating sessions and @current_user not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code here that is supposed to create a session upon login, and create "@current_user". However, neither of these things are working, and after 2 days of speculating, I can't figure out why.

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to login_path
       flash[:success] = "Account created. You may now log in"
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
      flash[:warning] = "Something went wrong. Try again."
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :jabber_id, :password)
  end
end
```

Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:name])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/posts'
    else
      session[:user_id] = nil
      flash[:warning] = "Failed login- try again"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    session[:session_id] = nil 
    redirect_to login_path 
  end
end
```

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def require_user 
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user 
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried debugging at `session[:user_id] = @user.id` to see if that code was actually hit?

Comment: what do you mean with "it's not working"?

Comment: what happens? tell us more

Comment: the session isn't created

Comment: So you get the "failed login" message? Do you have `has_secure_password` in your `User` model, and the `bcrypt` gem is installed?

Comment: No, the login doesn't fail, but the session creation does.

Comment: For your second question, yes on both counts.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your login form please, and the params your `sessions_controller` receives? It looks to me as if the line `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:name])` isn't getting the correct data in `params[:session][:name]`.

Comment: Instead of redirecting on failure you should `render :new`. This will make it so that the user does not have to reenter the inputs.